# jQuery text to input "takeover"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Strange one - I've setup a jQuery effect for editing a user's biography. Essentially they can click the text and create a textarea. This works fine, takeover works fine ... but only once?

html:

```
<p id="bioEdit" style="text-align: center;" data-editable>{{ some.user.bio }}</p>
```

js (streamlined and condensed):

```
$('#bioEdit').on('click', function() {
  var $input = $('<textarea class="form-control" style="160px" />').val( $('#bioEdit').text() );
  $('#bioEdit').replaceWith( $input );

  var save = function(){
    var $p = $('<p id="bioEdit" style="text-align: center;" data-editable />').text( $input.val() );
    var biography = $input.val()

    $input.replaceWith( $p );
  };
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
});
```

Can anyone replicate this once only input takeover? If so, do you know any ways to allow a user to keep editing more than once?

Comment: It would be nice and less complicated if you just toggle; hide and show the elements without remove/replace them, changing the document tree affect the performance, and clean code for others to read point of view

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at this line:

```
$('#bioEdit').replaceWith( $input );
```

You *remove* `#bioEdit`, putting `$input` on its place. This means, there is no more `#bioEdit` on the webpage. Therefore, `$('#bioEdit').on('click', ...)` takes effect only once.

What you could do is wrap `#bioEdit` in a container, and replace only the container content:

```
<div id="bioEditContainer">
<p id="bioEdit" style="text-align: center;" data-editable>{{ some.user.bio }}</p>
</div>
```

```js
$('#bioEditContainer').on('click', function() {
  $('#bioEdit').replaceWith( $input );
```

Comment: Worked fine but the answer below seemed a little more elegant?

Comment: (I didn’t downvote, but I’ll let the community decide which answer is to be accepted)

Comment: @MichaelRoberts The other solution sets onClick handler on whole document, meaning *every* click will be processed with this function. The end effect is same, but internally a check is needed for every mouse click - whether the click was on the `input` or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a downside of this approach. You can narrow down from document to the more specific container. However in real world it will not affect the performance in any way . Many 3rd party libraries listen add event handlers to document and body. + when it comes to jQuery we not talking about the performance anyway, since it's not known to have good performance.

Comment: (but I don't know why somebody will downvote since it's completely valid solution)

Comment: I agree that on webpages, especially if they're not very big, this solution won't have any noticeable impact. I'll add these comments to the answer shortly to clean space here.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh Actually, I think they would be a better fit for *your* answer, as they discuss *your* solution, not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You create new DOM element after edit while your click handler is bound to the old one. If you want your click handler to work on newly created elements as well you need to modify it to use delegated event.

```
$(document).on('click', '#bioEdit', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

You can also `.clone(true)` your `<p>` element before replacing it with `<input>` and then replace input with cloned copy. See https://api.jquery.com/clone/ . Providing `true` to clone will copy your element with the events.

However first approach will work better and will use less memory and resources than cloning element every time user wants to edit the text.

Comment: Elegant solution and worked without issue! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You lose your click event handler when you replace the element with `.replaceWith`

You can re-attach the event by creating a re-usable function:

```js
function editFn() {
  var $input = $('<textarea class="form-control" style="160px"/>').val($('#bioEdit').text());

  $('#bioEdit').replaceWith($input);

  var save = function() {
    var $p = $('<p id="bioEdit" style="text-align: center;" data-editable />').text($input.val());
    var biography = $input.val()

    $input.replaceWith($p);
     $('#bioEdit').on('click', editFn);
  };
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
 }

$('#bioEdit').on('click', editFn); // attach the event handler here
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="bioEdit" style="text-align: center;" data-editable>{{ some.user.bio }}</p>
```

Comment: @Michael This solution is probably the most optimal and is good in that it eliminates the need both of an additional container and a document-wide click handler.